# How to increase height of particular view postion using layout params

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-view, android-layoutparams

```
private void generateView() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        mview = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        mview.setBackgroundResource(R.color.grayColor);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(10, 40);
        layoutParams.setMargins(5, 0, 5, 0);
        mview.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        lnLinearlayout.addView(mview);
    }
}
```

Using this code I am able to display views like this:

```
||||||||||
```

I want to increase the height of the views at position 4 and 8. I am trying to do so using:

lnLinearlayout.getChildAt(4).setMinimumHeight(20)
   lnLinearlayout.getChildAt(8).setMinimumHeight(20)

but there is no change in the views. Can anyone please suggest how to increase the height of a particular view?

Answer (score 1):

Use below code..

```
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=(LinearLayout.LayoutParams)lnLinearlayout.getChildAt(4).getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.height=20;
    layoutParams=(LinearLayout.LayoutParams)lnLinearlayout.getChildAt(8).getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.height=20;
```

Comment: it becoming small but not bigger when i put 20 then i have put 100 then same hight @Mayank Pandya

Comment: Have you removed lnLinearlayout.getChildAt(4).setMinimumHeight(20)  this line? or Checked the height of LinearLayout in which you put all these children ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
lnLinearlayout.getChildAt(4).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(10, 200));
```

Comment: same thing i did still not working not able to increase hight

Comment: even i set 200 value then also no change

Comment: but its create new layout params we  have to use same param not new one

Comment: when you want to change the height of the LinearLayout you will need to set new layout params to that layout, instead of the previous one